# How to go about creating a parse tree in Python for grammar

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, nlp, parse-tree

I am trying to create a grammar parser for a general sentence structure I am studying. I have a lot of the logic down as the grammar structure is similar between most sentences. i.e. I have hardcoded if statements that check for indices of certain keywords and tokenize them appropriately which works to a degree. However, I would like to find a way to take this as a much more object oriented approach with a tree structure.

example sentences: `bob one three enemies flank south`

Example tokenization:

`bob` is a "name" token,  `one` is additional name information since it comes right after the first word in the sentence.

`enemies` is an "enemy declaration" token and `three` is additional enemy information since it comes right before the word "enemies".

`flank` is an action token and `south` is an "action" direction since it comes one word after the action.

These rules are consistent among all of the sentences in the language I am parsing.

So ideally what I want to do is a tree model architecture that parses the whole sentence, one word at a time, and tokenizes the special keywords like "enemies" or "flank", but I also need a way to capture the additional information that is attached to each keyword in proximity (preceding or succeeding), as given in the examples above. This is likely where my if statement logic would come in.

How can I set up an OOP approach to appending extra information into these classes. My early thoughts are to create `ClassTokens` for the keywords, but how would I handle attaching the descriptive words? Should I make classes for each of those words too or is this redundant?

Also, I imagine I need a separate class like a "Parser" that parses the entire sentence and maintains the sentence state as well as some lookahead or look prior functions? Just trying to brainstorm ideas and get some thoughts on how to make this flow together. Thank you.

E.g.

```
class Name:
      def __init__(self, name_keyword: str):
           self.name = name_word
           self.additional = []
          
      def add_additional(self, add_word: str):
           # if stuff then add it to self.additional

class Parser:
      def __init__(self, full_sentence: str):
           self.sentence = full_sentence.split() # initialize full sentence of words
           self.index = 0 # starting index

      def lookahead(self, n: int):
          return self.sentence[self.index + n]
   
      def lookprior(self, n: int):
          return self.sentence[self.index - n]
```

Comment: In the sentence `bob three enemies flank south`, does "three" modify "bob" or "enemies"?

Comment: @PaulMcG it depends on context. If the keyword after it is ```enemies``` then it is modifying ```enemies```, if it is ```enemy``` then ```three``` modifies ```bob```. The word ```single``` would be the preceding word if it was ```enemy``` to remove confusion from ```bob one enemy```. This is the rule I am faced with. General structure is name, enemy, action. With each of the three having potential add-on words that modify them. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I have many more questions. If you have 100 enemies, could it be written as "one hundred enemies"? What if you need multiple attributes for enemies, like "5 strong enemies"? What are the possible actions besides "flank"? Do they all have directions, or some other qualifier? This is a good time for you to write down this grammar using some level of BNF - it doesn't have to be super rigorous, but it will help you identify what ambiguities or problem areas you have in your grammar.

Comment: @PaulMcG In these sentences there will be no #s or punctuation. Strictly words. So yes 100 will be "one hundred" in the sentence. It is likely the numbers won't get over twenty but you are right these situations should be considered. As for actions there are several others and yes flank would follow with a general cardinality word giving 9 possible options (north, south, east, west, northeast, northwest, southeast, southwest). The idea is that each keyword in this structure has either a preceding or succeeding word and my first thought is to basically reference dictionaries of lists to find it